# JFrame doesn't show up using variable for width and height

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window {

    public Window(int width, int height, String title){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}

public class Driver {
    private final static int WIDTH = 500, HEIGHT = 500;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Window(WIDTH,HEIGHT,"Title");
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey there, welcome to Stack Overflow :-) Could you please post more information about what errors you're getting? Thanks

Comment: Hi, my code doesn't show the full window of JFrame. It works now though.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing `frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height));`, try doing this.

`frame.setSize(width, height);`

Answer (score 1):

frame.setSize(width,height);

OR

if you want to use 
frame.setPrefferedSize(new Dimension(width,height));

then 
You Have to set Minimum and Maximum Size

frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width,height));

frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width,height));